# fancyInput reset input status

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a plugin called fancyInput on a form, after submit, I would like to reset the input bar, but it does not work, I tried the code below but seems not working:

```
$.ajax({
      /*stuffs*/,
      success:function(){
                $("input[name='messaggio']").val('').fancyInput().clear();
      }
});
```

Another solution that I tried is:

```
$("input[name='messaggio']").attr('value','');
```

As suggested here: [fancyInput](https://github.com/yairEO/fancyInput/issues/30)

Do you have any ideas about how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: put a jsfiddle on that

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just reset the value of your input box -

```
$('.demo-fancyinput').val('');
```

and then call the fancy input on your input again, it should reset

```
$('.demo-fancyinput').fancyInput();
```

Demo - http://bitconfig.com/fancyinput/bitconfig_fancyinput.html

Change the text in the input box. Then click "Refresh" to reset the input text.